# Date picker value not updating in the view until calendar is opened

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two date pickers `startDate` and `endDate`. I am trying to implement basic date validation where the start date cannot be after the end date.

I need to ensure that
**if the user selects end date which is before the start date - then the start date should change to the selected end date.**

I am using `(dateChange)` event emitter and it changes the value of `startDate`in the model, however, the field value in the actual view does not update until I interact with the `startDate` date picker element.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Start date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDate" [value]="startDate"
        (dateChange)="changeStartDate($event)" [matDatepickerFilter]="startDateFilter">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDate">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #fromDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>End date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="toDate" [value]="endDate"
        (dateChange)="changeEndDate($event)" [matDatepickerFilter]="endDateFilter">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDate">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #toDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
startDateFilter = (selectedDate: Date | null): boolean => {
  return selectedDate < new Date()  && selectedDate < this.endDate;
}

endDateFilter = (selectedDate: Date | null): boolean => {
  return selectedDate < new Date();
}

changeStartDate(event) {
  this.startDate = event.value;
}

changeEndDate(event) {
  if (event.value < this.startDate) {
    this.startDate.setTime(event.value.getTime());
  }
  this.endDate = event.value;
}
```

**EDIT - variable declarations**

```
endDate = new Date();
startDate = new Date(this.endDate.getFullYear(), this.endDate.getMonth(), this.endDate.getDate()-7);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correction to `startDate` is not picked up immediately by data binding because the bound value, which is the Date object reference, does not change. You can make sure that the change is detected by creating a new Date object:

```js
changeEndDate(event) {
  if (event.value < this.startDate) {
    this.startDate = new Date(event.value);  // <-- create new Date object
  }
  this.endDate = event.value;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4evja?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.ts) for a demo.